# Generating k-partite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, mathematical-software, nauty

Does there exist an efficient algorithm for generating all non-isomorphic k-partite graphs up to a certain order $n$? I've read through the nauty tutorial, but it doesn't look like anything beyond bipartite graph generation is supported. Any help, whether it's a pointer to a paper(s) or source code, would be immensely useful in my research.

EDIT: One variation of my problem requires that all graphs are also regular, so I can assume a fixed degree for every node. I'm still not sure if that helps.

Comment: Have you checked Donald Knuth's TAOCP volume 4 for references yet?  I think it covers similar problems, such as generating all trees.

Comment: I have not. I'll have to get my hands on a copy of that book. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Do you want graphs that can be properly coloured with $t$ colours, or graphs that *are* properly coloured with $t$ colours?  The generation problem is entirely different for these two options.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like graphs that are properly colored with t colors (i.e. $\chi(G) = t$).

Answer (score 3):

For bipartite graphs you can use McKay's genbg program that is shipped with the [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) package. For small values of $n$ (up to 11) you can use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) in the following way:

```
sage: for G in graphs.nauty_geng("n"):
....:     if G.chromatic_number() == k:
....:         # do something with it
```

If you need something more efficient then you'll have to be more specific. Do you impose any other structure on your graphs? What values of $n$ are you interested in? What values of $k$?

Comment: As I mention in the edit above, I can impose the constraint that the graph is regular. I am interested in as many values of $n$ and $k$ as possible, so long as $k \geq 3$.

Comment: You can do that quite quickly (less than a day) for $n$ up to $10-11$ For $12$ its also quite feasible but for $n > 13$ I don't think there is a way to do this without some additional constraints.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only other constraint I can impose is that of degree regularity. It looks like I'm a bit stuck here. :-\